# jQuery Singleton

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have something like in a file say test.js:

```
(function($){    
$.test= function(){ 
    alert('test');
    }
 })(jQuery);
 jQuery.test();
```

Now if test.js is loaded twice in my page i.e. src=test.js in two different locations, it gives alert twice. I want it to be like a singleton. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: It's a bit unclear if you ware trying avoid _calling_ test twice, or _defining_ test twice.

Comment: Correct me if this is a stupid question, but why would you need to load a file more than once?  Why not just store the function in a variable and call it when you need it in the document?

Comment: @Squeegy I am calling and defining test twice. I want that to happen only once.

Comment: @helixed the problem is that some users include the JS file twice, this causes an issue. Am trying to fix that. By users I mean site owners.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a conditional shortcut:

```
(function($){    
    !$.test && $.test= function(){ 
        alert('test');
    }
})(jQuery);

jQuery.test();
```

`!$.test` evaluates to `true` if `$.test` is not defined and the code on the rightside after the `&&` is executed. Otherwise, it'll just skip the part. Another useful pattern for that could look like:

```
$.test = $.test || function() {
     alert('test');
}
```

This does the same thing actually. If `$.test` is already defined its used, otherwise assign the anonymous function to `$.test`. Both versions can (and probably should) get optimized but not just checking if they were defined, but also if they are from type `function`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this?

```
if(typeof $.test == "undefined") {
  (function($){    
    $.test= function(){ 
      alert('test');
    }
  })(jQuery);
  jQuery.test();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(function($){    
  $.test = function() {
    if (!$.test.hasBeenRun) {
      $.test.hasBeenRun = true;
      alert('test');
    }
  }
  $.test.hasBeenRun = false;
})(jQuery);
jQuery.test();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Why don't you extract this shared code into a third file?**

Other than that, it depends on what the code does. Generally, you could wrap the whole function in a condition and only execute "if a conflicting thing has not yet been performed.